# How to fix get request returning nothing in Postman?

Tags: php, sql, rest

I'm learning REST API basic create, read, delete and update using pure PHP with no framework (i have no prior knowledge of REST API and this is my first time trying to get into it and learn it) and i have a strange problem with `GET` request not returning results with one property on and off when reading data,

**read.php**

```
<?php
  // Headers
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  include_once '../../config/Database.php';
  include_once '../../models/Capteur.php';

  // Instantiate DB & connect
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();

  // Instantiate capteur object
  $capteur = new Capteur($db);

  // Capteur read query
  $result = $capteur->read();

  // Get row count
  $num = $result->rowCount();

  // Check if any categories
  if($num > 0) {
        // Cat array
        $cap_arr = array();
        $cap_arr['data'] = array();

        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          extract($row);

          $cap_item = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'code_capteur' => $code_capteur,
            'etat' => $etat,
            'etab' => $etab,
            'created_at' => $created_at,
            'updated_at' => $updated_at
          );

          // Push to "data"
          array_push($cap_arr['data'], $cap_item);
        }

        // Turn to JSON & output
        echo json_encode($cap_arr);

  } else {
        // No Categories
        echo json_encode(
          array('message' => 'No Categories Found')
        );
  }
```

when i remove `'etab' => $etab` it outputs data fine

This is my class:
**Capteur.php**

```
<?php
  class Capteur {
    // DB stuff
    private $conn;
    private $table = 'capteurs';

    // Post Properties
    public $id;
    public $code_capteur;
    public $etat;
    public $etab;
    public $created_at;
    public $updated_at;

    // Constructor with DB
    public function __construct($db) {
      $this->conn = $db;
    }

    // Get Posts
    public function read() {
      // Create query
      $query = 'SELECT *  FROM ' . $this->table . '
                                ORDER BY
                                  created_at DESC';

      // Prepare statement
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

      // Execute query
      $stmt->execute();

      return $stmt;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

this is my database structure:
[image]

output:
[image]

Comment: 1) Check the return status, is it 500 or 200? 2) Check your log 3) try var_dump() data before the echo, make sure the data is there.

Comment: what status do you get in response? is there any error? did you check logs or enable errors from php.ini?

Comment: I edited original post with output

Comment: @catcon it's 200

Comment: try to dump like `print_r($etab);exit;` or `var_dump($etab);exit` check what it returns

Comment: nope got nothing @devnullΨ

Comment: thats strange. from where you get `$etab` variable? have you enabled display errors? does it reach `echo json_encode($cap_arr);` ? put dump before it and check what `$cap_arr` contains.  maybe problem somewhere else

Comment: Hey, I think you should use `$cap_arr['data']` on `json_encode` instead of `$cap_arr` only. It's obviously different variable.

Comment: I would strongly discourage **ever** using `extract()`. For one, it presents a security risk and two, you don't know what variables you're going to declare with it

Comment: You can replace your entire loop with `echo json_encode(['data' => $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)]);`. Also, make sure [PDO is set to throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52324601/283366) and that you will be able to see them if they happen. See [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)